# PHP: assign function to class method

Tags: php, function, oop, methods

How can I assign a function to a method in a class in PHP? I tried the following:

```
class Something{
    public function __construct(){
        $functionNames = array('foo', 'bar')

        $variable = 'blablabla';

        foreach($functionNames as $functionName){
            if(method_exists($this, $functionName))
                continue;

            $this->{$functionName}() = function($params){ //should create the methods "foo" and "bar"
                echo $variable; //should echo 'blablabla' (I know that the variable was declared outside this function, but how can I access it anyway?)
            }; //the error points to here
        }
    }
}
```

But this code gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context
```

Does anyone know how I can assign the anonymous function to the class method, while also still being able to access variables outside that function?

Comment: I do not think that is possible in PHP in the way that you are doing it. I think you have to instantiate an object or have a function return something that assigns something to a variable. Not a bad question though.

Comment: You can't return in a class constructor. It'll throw an error. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @versalle88 yeah, that's true... I actually have a foreach loop and the `return;` is a `continue;`, but I decided to simplify the code a bit since (I thought) it wasn't necessary. I'll edit it though

Comment: Although it still won't work, when you assign an anonymous function, you should not use braces on the variable: `$this->{$functionName[0]} = function($params){`

Comment: I don't see how this can work.  Where is the value of $variable going to be stored once the constructor returns?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve by dynamically creating functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing `foreach($functionNames as $functionName){` which means that `$functionName` is a *string*, not an array.  So, don't use `$functionName[0]`.

`method_exists` takes 2 parameters.  One is the object and the other is the method name.  It should be:

```
method_exists($this, $functionName)
```

As for creating the function, you don't need `()` on the *left* side of the `=`.  It should be:

```
$this->$functionName = function($params) use($variable){
    echo $variable;
};
```

The `use($variable)` is needed to tell PHP to use that variable inside the function.  That's how closures work in PHP, it's different than other languages.

So, your class should look like:

```
class Something{
    public function __construct(){
        $functionNames = array('foo', 'bar');

        $variable = 'blablabla';

        foreach($functionNames as $functionName){
            if(method_exists($this, $functionName)){
                continue;
            }

            $this->$functionName = function($params) use($variable){
                echo $variable;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Problem here is that in this way of making functions, you are not actually creating a class method, but instead creating a class variable that contains a function.

So, you need to call it like so:

```
$test = new Something;
$foo = $test->foo;

$foo('abc');
```

You can't just do `$test->foo('abc');`.

EDIT: Another thing you can do is use PHP's `__call` "magic method".  This will be ran whenever you do `->funcName()`, regardless of whether the method exists or not.  Using that method, you can just check to see if the method called was `'foo'` or `'bar'`.  See this example:

```
class Something{
    private $variable;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->variable = 'blablabla';
    }

    public function __call($name, $params=array()){
        if(method_exists($this, $name)){
            // This makes sure methods that *do* exist continue to work
            return call_user_func(array($this, $name), $params);
        }
        else{
            $functionNames = array('foo', 'bar');

            if(in_array($name, $functionNames)){
                // You called ->foo() or ->bar(), so do something
                // If you'd like you can call another method in the class
                echo $this->variable;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, now you can do the following:

```
$test = new Something;
$test->foo('abc');  // Will echo "blablabla"
```